# password input custom

Tags: scala, lift

Greetings

In my User.scala file:

I'm using the next class to customize the password input

The code is the next

```
import net.liftweb.mapper.MappedPassword 

[...]

class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {

      [...]

          override def _toForm: Box[NodeSeq] = {
            S.fmapFunc({s: List[String] => this.setFromAny(s)}){funcName =>
              Full(
                   <tr>
                   <td>{S.??("repeat")}</td>
                   <td><input id={fieldId} type='password' name={funcName} value={is.toString}/> </td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                   <td>{S.??("repeat")}<td>
                   <td><input type='password' name={funcName} value={is.toString}/></td>
                   </tr>
                   )
            }
          }

[...]

}
```

the compiler displays the following error:

```
[ERROR] ....../org/santix/model/User.scala:209: error: value setFromAny is not a member of org.santix.model.User
[INFO]             S.fmapFunc({s: List[String] => this.setFromAny(s)}){funcName =>
```

anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's just too little information to answer, but I can see some points here...

First, I imagine you might be copying from some example, since you use `this.setFromAny`. The code containing this snippet is inside the class `User`, which extends `MegaProtoUser[User]`. Alas, `MegaProtoUser` does not have any method `setFromAny`, and I imagine your own class `User` doesn't either, and this is the primary cause of the error.

Now, `setFromAny` is part of the class `MappedPassword`, which you import, but doesn't seem to use in any place, so I don't know why you imported it. However, I can see that `MegaProtoUser` has a member which returns a `MappedPassword`. This member is called `password`, so I imagine this might work:

```
S.fmapFunc({s: List[String] => this.password.setFromAny(s)}){funcName =>
```

Answer (score -1):

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!

```
class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {
  ...   

  override lazy val password = new MyPassword(this) {

    override def _toForm: Box[NodeSeq] = {
      S.fmapFunc({s: List[String] => this.setFromAny(s)})
      {funcName =>
        Full(
          <tr>
            <td>{ passwordDisplayName }</td>
            <td>
              <input id={fieldId} type='password' name={funcName} value=''/>
              <!-- by sanx, value={is.toString} -->
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>{S.??("repeat")}</td>
            <td>
              <input type='password' name={funcName} value=''/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
    }

  }
}
```